# Why the original array items are also get deleted in an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, deep-copy

I add and remove values from adapter objects through adapter's add() and clear() and they are removing and adding elements to a list, which is not referenced from any place inside the adapter. I have orig list, which sits outside the adapter and has a reference from inside the adapter to the not changing outside reference and inside the adapter I only have reference to a *new* list, which I filled using the old original list with the same objects. How come that the new list affects the old list?

```
class LanguageItemArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<com.anysoftkeyboard.ui.settings.LanguageItem>{
    private Context mContext;
    private final ArrayList<com.anysoftkeyboard.ui.settings.LanguageItem> origList = new ArrayList<com.anysoftkeyboard.ui.settings.LanguageItem>();
    private final ArrayList<com.anysoftkeyboard.ui.settings.LanguageItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<com.anysoftkeyboard.ui.settings.LanguageItem>();

    LanguageItemArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes ArrayList<com.anysoftkeyboard.ui.settings.LanguageItem> list, ArrayList<com.anysoftkeyboard.ui.settings.LanguageItem> filteredList){
        super(context, 0, filteredList);
        mContext = context;
        origList.addAll(list); //THIS WORKS WELL. 
        //THIS BREAKS EVERYTHING -> 
        //origlist = list;
    }

    public void fillData(){
        filteredList.addAll(origList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if (listItem == null)
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.languages_list_row, parent, false);
        com.anysoftkeyboard.ui.settings.LanguageItem currentItem = filteredList.get(position);

        TextView title = listItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(currentItem.getTitle());

        return listItem;
    }

    private Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<com.anysoftkeyboard.ui.settings.LanguageItem> tempList=new ArrayList<com.anysoftkeyboard.ui.settings.LanguageItem>();
            //constraint is the result from text you want to filter against.
            //objects is your data set you will filter from
            if(constraint != null) {
                int length= origList.size();
                int i=0;
                while(i<length){
                    LanguageItem item= origList.get(i);
                    if(item.toString().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        tempList.add(item);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                //following two lines is very important
                //as publish result can only take FilterResults objects
                filterResults.values = tempList;
                filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            }

            return filterResults;
        }

        //HERE ARE THE AFFECTING METHODS:
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredList.clear();

            clear(); //******THIS METHOD REMOVES THE VALUES from origList as well******
            filteredList.addAll((Collection<? extends LanguageItem>) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            //*****THIS ADDS VALUES TO ORIG LIST AS WELL. WHY?*****
            for(LanguageItem item: filteredList)
                add(item); 

        }
    };

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return myFilter;
    }
}
```

Why does the original list get edited while I change only the filtered list?

EDIT:

```
ArrayAdapter<com.anysoftkeyboard.ui.settings.LanguageItem> adapter = new LanguageItemArrayAdapter(getContext(), simpleLanguageItems, simpleLanguageItems);
    ((LanguageItemArrayAdapter) adapter).fillData();;
```

(I know the fix, I don't understand the reason - fix is in code below if you're struggling the problem with Custom Adapter Filter like I did.)

Comment: In the constructor I would have expected `this.filteredList = filteredList;` Or better remove the field `filteredList` as it seems to be held be the parent class. The code seems a bit worth redesigning.

Comment: @Joop Eggen let me know if you know the answer, if needed I'll rewrite compile and edit it again.

Comment: Can you share the code of how you construct the parameters `list` and `filteredList`, and also how you invoke `LanguageItemArrayAdapter` constructor?

Comment: @VitaliPom sorry, too confusing for me. I am not necessarily "better" than you.

Comment: `origList` and `filteredList` constructors are sown in code. `LanguageItemArrayAdapter` and `list` I'll show you right away.

Comment: @Joop ♥ cool sorry. I have 2-3 bots that vote down every question I write here, today happened again. I thought it's again one of them. Sorry, yeah the code is dirty a bit and requires cleaning. Meanwhile in general it's okay, cause the problem is interesting. I apologies again, I find good people are rare. Yes when I fix in the repo, I'll fix here as well. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: P.S. Maybe `/*...*/` should be replaced by a space, as `-/**/-` are two minus operators, not a decrement operator`.

Comment: Oh, these are added already only in here, not in the original code :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code passes the same instance of `ArrayList` to the `LanguageItemArrayAdapter`

```java
new LanguageItemArrayAdapter(getContext(), simpleLanguageItems, simpleLanguageItems)
```

To understand why `add(…)` and `clear()` in `ArrayAdapter` also modifies the same object you need to look at their implementations from [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java).

```java
public void clear() {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (mOriginalValues != null) {
            mOriginalValues.clear();
        } else {
            mObjects.clear();
        }
        …
    }
    …
}
```

`clear()` will modify `mObjects` and `mOriginalValues` (you will notice that other functions in `ArrayAdapter` do the same). You will need to read the code inside `ArrayFilter` to understand how they are modified.

```
private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
  /* 
  mObjects will contain only items fulfilling the filter conditions. 
  Original items are copied into mOriginalValues 
  */
}
```

Looking at the constructor (and constructor chain) you will find that your class constructor has

```java
super(context, 0, filteredList);
```

that will end up calling

```java
private ArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, 
        @LayoutRes int resource,
        @IdRes int textViewResourceId, 
        @NonNull List<T> objects, 
        boolean objsFromResources) {
    …
    mObjects = objects;
    …
}
```

This allows `ArrayAdapter` to modify your `simpleLanguageItems` instance.

Comment: You're my hero! 